# TFS: cannot set up new build

Tags: tfs, build, build-automation

I have set up TFS Build Service on one machine in the network. Now
I want to create a build. When logging to Team Explorer (under my personal TFS account)
I see a Build subfolder in my project folder. However there is a small red cross icon

[alt text http://s001.radikal.ru/i195/1001/fa/8196d29e4f9b.jpg](http://s001.radikal.ru/i195/1001/fa/8196d29e4f9b.jpg)

Does it have to do with my account rights? I belong to Contributors group.
How can I create a new build?

MSDN says

> To create a new build type
>
> 1.
>         In Team Explorer, select the project for which you want to create a
>   new build type.
>      2.
>         On the Build menu, select New Team Build Type.

Where is Build Menu? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to clean up TFS cache.