# TFS: cannot setup up new build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

I have a problem that is described here: [TFS: cannot set up new build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146198/tfs-cannot-set-up-new-build)
I use Visual Studio 2008. Unfortunately, the solution provided there, didn't help.
I tried to remove and add again my TFS server - no help. Also, it's not a problem with security policies or lack of proper right, because I can initiate a new build, with the same user through Visual Studio 2005, also installed on my computer.
In addition my colleagues have no problems at all.

If someone else have experienced similar problem - I will appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did. I don't know why the problem is fixed, but it's ok ... for now.
I installed the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools and exclusively installed the integration of the tools with Visual Studio. Then I did the following instructions again:
I decided to add my user (just me, not from some domain group) in to the permission menu options ... Then, from security option menu I checked the 'start a build' option at my user and restarted the Visual Studio.

After restarting the Source control menu is a little bit different from what it was before, but at least I can start builds now. Hope It's forever :)

Answer (score 1):

If your getting the red cross it is likely that it is a permissions problem. From the 'Team Explorer' window within VS2008, right-click on your project node and select the 'Team Project Settings->Group Membership' menu option. From there trace down the group that your user belongs to.

Next, again right-click on your project node in the 'Team Explorer' window, this time selecting the 'Team Project Settings->Security' option. Within this dialog, find the security settings for your user group. Ensure that the 'Allow' checkbox is set for the 'Start a build' property. Confirm any changes and exit.

I have found that it is best to restart IIS on the TFS server to ensure that the chances are picked up.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me!
Here what happened: I checked that my user appears in several groups and in the security menu I checked that at least one of these groups have the right to start a build. So far .. no good.
Then I decided to add my user (just me, not from some domain group) in to the permission menu options ... Then, from security option menu I checked the 'start a build' option at my user and restarted the Visual Studio. And it worked !

Still It's a mystery why is all the mess, since I should be able to build like everyone else in the group!

Comment: After restarting the Visual Studio though ... it is still with no build option :( ... So the problem is still open! I suppose there is something messing with my permissions, but What could it be ?!

Comment: Configuring TFS can be a royal PITA at times, glad I could help.

Comment: It is still an open issue though :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the server running TFS 2005 or 2008?

Have you tried running the diagnostics in the [BPA Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx#bpa)?

EDIT:

Team Build had many breaking changes between 2005 and 2008.  VS 2008 cannot create new build definitions on a 2005 server.  Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/07/27/team-build-compatibility-between-2005-and-2008.aspx

Comment: Well, it's working actually. And in addition, It's working  for all my colleagues flawlessly for a year. It's only me, having some problems for a 2-3 weeks.

Comment: To be clear, you can queue builds, but you cannot create new build definitions.  For that you need to use VS 2005 or upgrade to TFS 2008.